# AWS security group inbound rule. allow lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I run a service on my EC2 instance and I want to setup an inbound rule that only allows my lambda function to access it. The security group allows me to restrict access by a specific IP, but I don't think that lambda functions have a specific IP assigned. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: what was your solution to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 63):

If you are enabling VPC access for your Lambda function, as per [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/), then you will create a security group for your Lambda functions to use within your VPC. All you need to do at that point is go into the security group your EC2 instance is using and grant access to the security group the Lambda function is using. This is the method I recommend.

If you are not using VPC access then your EC2 instance would need to be publicly accessible and you would basically be going over the internet to access the EC2 instance from the Lambda function. If that's the case then there is no good way to restrict that in the security group. You could (with difficulty) open it up to only requests that [originate within AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html), but that still leaves it open to all other users of AWS. If you must go over the internet to access your EC2 instance from Lambda then it would be best to send some sort of security token with each request Lambda sends, and ignore any requests on the EC2 server that don't contain that security token.

Comment: Assuming the Lambda is setup with VPC, then what should be configured in the security group created for the Lambda- meaning what inbound/outbound rules should be setup in this security group?

Comment: @museshad outbound rules should be empty (the default which allows all outbound). The inbound rules should also be empty since inbound rules for Lambda don't make sense, due to the fact that Lambda functions don't sit around listening for incoming network traffic, they only run when invoked by the AWS API. You only need to assign a security group to the Lambda function so you can reference it in the inbound rules of your other VPC security groups.

Comment: Apart from this, security group of lambda should have inbound rule for allowing all traffic to the security group of VPC endpoint, and further : security group of VPC endpoint should have inbound rule of allowing port 443 to all IPV4 as well...

Comment: @MihirBhatt You are correct about the security group of the VPC endpoint. You are incorrect about the Lambda security group. A Lambda function never receives a direct inbound network connection, so it does not need inbound rules at all.

Comment: @MihirBhatt no, absolutely. VPC endpoints do not generate inbound traffic, they are only connecting your resources in your VPC with an external service. The only needed rule in a VPCe SG is the egress one (only 443 port). Not generating connections there is no need to allow traffic from VPCe, whatever the resource is using it (Lambda, EC2, etc) because SGs are stateful and responses are automatically allowed. 

On the other hand, Lambda is invoked ALWAYS via API, no ingress rule for it needed too.

Answer (score 23):

What happens if we want our Lambda function to access resources in our VPC? This is a bit of a puzzlement because the Lambda function does not have a stable IP address that we can use as a source in our VPC security groups or in our subnet ACLs.

AWS has overcome these limitations by allowing you to specify a subnet and security group to associate with the Lambda function. You would think that this security group and subnet ACL would control traffic in and out of the Lambda function, but this is wrong. Firstly, Lambda functions do not listen for traffic on any port and so the concept of inbound traffic to a Lambda function is not applicable. Secondly, outbound connections from the Lambda function to VPC resources are not restricted in any way by the Lambda function’s security group. So, what is this mysterious Lambda function security group good for and how does it work?

It turns out that the Lambda function’s security group is just a naming placeholder that we can use in our other EC2 security groups. For example, a Lambda function can make a GET request to an EC2 instance on a private subnet in your VPC. We start out with two security groups. The first one is a normal security group that controls traffic to and from our EC2 instance that will be serving up the files on port 8080. It has a single inbound rule that allows port 8080 traffic with a source being the Lambda function’s security group. Recall that security group rules can specify source or destination as another security group which is a placeholder for all the hosts that are members of that source or destination security group.

The Lambda function’s security group has ***no rules*** whatsoever. None are required. It is merely a placeholder for the Lambda function that allows us to specify the Lambda function as source in our other EC2 security groups. Remember that the Lambda function has a random IP address that changes from day to day and hour to hour, so it is not possible to specify it as source for the inbound traffic to the EC2 instance.
Security groups normally control traffic in and out of a network interface but in the case of an AWS Lambda function security group, there is no interface and no rules – it is merely a placeholder.

Comment: Thanks. I think you've explained the underlying concept quite well. However, my actual exp has againsted you suggestions re
"Secondly, outbound connections from the Lambda function to VPC resources are not restricted in any way by the Lambda function’s security group."
or
"The Lambda function’s security group has no rules whatsoever. None are required."
I found that I'll still need to keep the outbound rules in the Lambda security group, otherwise it won't work.
For inbound rules, as you said, I've 0 rule in the Lambda security group.

Comment: The statements related to egress/outbound rules on Lambda function security groups are incorrect. Lambda function SG egress rules operate the same way as they do for EC2 instances.

Answer (score 8):

A Lambda with no VPC association can reach the Internet through outgoing logical Network path(Managed by AWS Network out of the box).If that Lambda wants to send traffic to any Internet reachable resources on the recieving ends you will see traffic is comming from an arbitrary Public IP address (obviously from Amazon Registered IPs). This will not be a single fixed address. So it is almost impossible to Allowlist incomming IP in your EC2's SG since the next time the IP that traffic is being sent from can change (although from AWS CIDR range but for sure allowlisting that in SG will defeat the original security purpose).

However if you asscoiate the Lambda with a VPC, You can have extra controls over in the VPC Network. This is Because then Lambdas will be assigned with Internal Network Interfaces from your VPC IP range. Let's say you want that EC2 server to only be accessible from the Internal vpc network, therefor you place that EC2 in your Internal Subnet with no Public IP assigned. Now You can set SG on your EC2 to only accept IP from Internal CIDR range of your VPC. Since Lambda is now part of your VPC it will get IP from it's Private Subnet (via ENI) you can add internal range to the the SG configured for your EC2 (just make sure not running out of IPs, If you are going to have lots of Lambdas run in parallel you need to have pretty handful  of IPs defined in your VPC CIDR range).

Now in the given scenario if you want to provide Internet connectivity to resources located in Private Subnet of your VPC you can add a NAT Gateway in Public Subnet(Routable Subnet to IGW) and  make sure Internal resources from your Private Subnet can Route to that. Therefore all your component within the Internal subnet will be assigned with a Routing Tables pointing to NAT and subsequently the the Internet.

Comment: The statement "Lambda with no VPC association will be on the Internet and assigned with an arbitrary Public IP" is misleading. Lambda functions don't have assigned public IPs. They have network interfaces with assigned private IPs and they potentially have a route via NAT to the internet. By default, i.e. if you do not configure a Lambda function to connect to your VPC, then the Lambda service runs your functions in an AWS-managed VPC with access to AWS services and the internet (via AWS-managed NAT).

Answer (score 3):

Your Lambda will have a temporary IP assigned to it when it runs.
If you configure the IAM role attached to it so it can Allow/Revoke Security Group Ingress, you can make it "let himself in" to your sec group.
Check out [this](https://medium.com/@griggheo/modifying-ec2-security-groups-via-aws-lambda-functions-115a1828cdb6) article for an example on adding an IP or CIDR block to your inbound list. 
I would clean it up straight away when the function is done.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer below articles to do the same,

1. https://medium.com/@justanotherspyy/how-to-connect-your-lambda-function-securely-to-your-private-rds-instances-in-your-vpc-29789220a33

2. https://medium.com/orchestrated/steps-to-secure-aws-serverless-lambda-part-1-a6e5d1b05f45

The summary would be,

1. Create a role for Lambda using below two policies,

AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole — provides CloudWatch logging.

AWSLambdaENIManagementAccess — provides ENI description, creation, and deletion.

2. Put lambda in the same VPC of EC2 and create a security group for the lambda function.

3. Put this security group in EC2's security group's inbound rules.

Answer (score -1):

> Apart from creating VPC endpoint for secret manager

security group of lambda should have inbound rule for allowing all traffic to the security group of VPC endpoint, and further : security group of VPC endpoint should have inbound rule of allowing port 443 to all IPV4 as well...[image]

[image]

Comment: The ingress part is totally wrong.