# Connect OpenSearch Cluster to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, amazon-opensearch

I have an opensearch cluster in AWS and have a lambda that uses the OpenSearch API for work like repository registration etc.
I read that we needed VPC config for the VPC which I did and it worked out well.
Now I need to specify security group for the lambda which to me makes no sense because inbound connections are done internally via AWS Lambda API and for outbound connections, I've read "Secondly, outbound connections from the Lambda function to VPC resources are not restricted in any way by the Lambda function’s security group." in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468388/aws-security-group-inbound-rule-allow-lambda-function) stackoverflow discussion (the 2nd answer).

Also is this true that outbound connections are not restricted for lambda?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61019982/271415) that you point to is incorrect. In general, a security group controls the traffic that is allowed to reach and leave the resources that it's associated with. For Lambda functions, the ingress rules are not relevant because Lambda functions do not allow inbound connections. The egress rules are relevant, however, and operate just as they would with an EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes. thanks.  I made the changes and it worked